# access to enterprise application (EA) in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

what is a significance of "Users and groups" under EA?

1. adding a person will give same access to person as that EA?
2. adding a SP will do what? added SP will not have same access as EA?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just creating the identity (User type or Service Principal) you will not give any role.

After you create the user, you can assign any role that you require to give to the identity.

#### Assign Azure AD

1. Sign in to the Azure AD admin center.
2. Select Azure Active Directory > Roles and administrators to see the list of all available roles.
3. Select a role to see its assignments.
   To help you find the role you need, use Add filters to filter the roles.
4. Select Add assignments and then select the users you want to assign to this role.
   If you see something different from the following picture, you might have PIM enabled. See the next section.
5. Select Add to assign the role.
   Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/manage-roles-portal

To Grant a user access to Azure resources you can follow this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal

Hopes this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

The users and groups tab specifies who can access the application. This is based on the assumption that the app is 'closed' in the properties tab.